# extract props from function into components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing a react component I am trying to extract name from App function into Welcome so this should appear Hello, Sara/Hello, Jone and Hello, David. Currently it is appearing as only Hello, and not name after the Hello,.

I am importing this component in other main file in the same folder.

Here is the code

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Welcome extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: ""
    };
  }
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Welcome name="Sara" />
      <Welcome name="Jone" />
      <Welcome name="David" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Welcome;
```

Comment: You are exporting the `Welcome` component. Don't you want to export the `App` and use that?

Comment: because you are exporting the Welcome component, you need to export the App component, `export default App;`

Comment: I think @Tholle is correct, as the code works fine, otherwise: https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/

Comment: Hi Tholle, you are correct, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the component just renders `Hello,` is because you are currently exporting the `Welcome` component from the module.

Export the `App` component instead and it will work as expected.

```
export default App;
```